# R: Tidy data format to human-readable format

Tags: r, dplyr

I have species data in a tidy data format. For inclusion in a report, I need to reduce the width of the table, by listing the higher orders (kingdom, phylum, class, etc) only once for each group.

I currently have:

[image]

... and need to get to something like:
[image]

... or something like:

[image]

... where each higher order is given only once, with each species within that higher order listed below.

This list is long, so needs to be script based. I have looked at using `dplyr` but don't see a way to achieve this.

Below is reproducible example data if needed.

```
exampledata <- structure(list(KINGDOM = c("Animalia", "Animalia", "Animalia", 
                                   "Animalia", "Animalia", "Animalia", "Animalia", "Animalia", "Animalia", 
                                   "Animalia", "Animalia", "Animalia"), PHYLYM = c("Chordata", "Chordata", 
                                                                                   "Chordata", "Chordata", "Chordata", "Chordata", "Chordata", "Chordata", 
                                                                                   "Chordata", "Chordata", "Chordata", "Chordata"), CLASS = c("Amphibia", 
                                                                                                                                              "Amphibia", "Amphibia", "Amphibia", "Amphibia", "Aves", "Aves", 
                                                                                                                                              "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves"), ORDER = c("Anura", "Anura", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "Anura", "Anura", "Anura", "Accipitriformes", "Ciconiiformes", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "Gruiformes", "Passeriformes", "Passeriformes", "Pelecaniformes", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "Pelecaniformes"), FAMILY = c("Ranidae", "Ranidae", "Rhacophoridae", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "Rhacophoridae", "Rhacophoridae", "Accipitridae", "Ciconiidae", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "Gruidae", "Muscicapidae", "Muscicapidae", "Threskiornithidae", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "Threskiornithidae"), SCIENTIFICNAME = c("Hylarana attigua", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "Hylarana taipehensis", "Philautus", "Polypedates leucomystax", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "Theloderma asperum", "Aviceda jerdoni", "Leptoptilos javanicus", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "Antigone antigone", "Cyanoptila cyanomelana", "Cyornis hainanus", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "Pseudibis davisoni", "Thaumatibis gigantea"), OTHERDATA = c("XYZ", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "ABC", "XYZ", "ABC", "XYZ", "XYZ", "ABC", "XYZ", "ABC", "ABC", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "XYZ", "XYZ")), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please include data in a reproducible and copy&paste-able format. Screenshots of code/data are never useful, as it's not easy to extract data from an image. It might be useful to take a look at how to provide a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: You might try the `gt` package for its row labels: https://github.com/rstudio/gt   This could also probably be done in `dplyr` using `mutate_all` and something to change all values to blank if the next entry is the same.

Comment: You could use `collapse_rows()` from kable: https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is generally a bad idea to remove data however I see the use case.

Provided you have your data in the correct order already you could do something like this:

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(Species = if_else(duplicated(Species),"", as.character(Species)))
```

Note that the `as.character()` is only required as `Species` is a factor in this dataset.

---

Edit for example data:

```
exampledata %>% 
  mutate_at(vars("KINGDOM", "PHYLYM", "CLASS","ORDER", "FAMILY", "SCIENTIFICNAME"), ~ if_else(duplicated(.x),"", as.character(.x)) )
```

gives a table like this:

```
    KINGDOM   PHYLYM    CLASS           ORDER            FAMILY          SCIENTIFICNAME OTHERDATA
1  Animalia Chordata Amphibia           Anura           Ranidae        Hylarana attigua       XYZ
2                                                                  Hylarana taipehensis       ABC
3                                                 Rhacophoridae               Philautus       XYZ
4                                                               Polypedates leucomystax       ABC
5                                                                    Theloderma asperum       XYZ
6                        Aves Accipitriformes      Accipitridae         Aviceda jerdoni       XYZ
7                               Ciconiiformes        Ciconiidae   Leptoptilos javanicus       ABC
8                                  Gruiformes           Gruidae       Antigone antigone       XYZ
9                               Passeriformes      Muscicapidae  Cyanoptila cyanomelana       ABC
10                                                                     Cyornis hainanus       ABC
11                             Pelecaniformes Threskiornithidae      Pseudibis davisoni       XYZ
12                                                                 Thaumatibis gigantea       XYZ
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well. The HTML equivilent of this is `collapse_rows()` from kableExtra

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having blank cells, if you want to reduce data I would suggest `group_by` higher orders and save the other details as a comma-separated string.

```
library(dplyr)

exampledata %>%
   group_by(KINGDOM, PHYLYM, CLASS, ORDER, FAMILY) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(SCIENTIFICNAME, OTHERDATA), toString)


#   KINGDOM  PHYLYM   CLASS    ORDER         FAMILY         SCIENTIFICNAME                                 OTHERDATA   
#  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>         <chr>          <chr>                                          <chr>       
#1 Animalia Chordata Amphibia Anura         Ranidae        Hylarana attigua, Hylarana taipehensis         XYZ, ABC    
#2 Animalia Chordata Amphibia Anura         Rhacophoridae  Philautus, Polypedates leucomystax, Theloderm… XYZ, ABC, X…
#3 Animalia Chordata Aves     Accipitrifor… Accipitridae   Aviceda jerdoni                                XYZ         
#4 Animalia Chordata Aves     Ciconiiformes Ciconiidae     Leptoptilos javanicus                          ABC         
#5 Animalia Chordata Aves     Gruiformes    Gruidae        Antigone antigone                              XYZ         
#6 Animalia Chordata Aves     Passeriformes Muscicapidae   Cyanoptila cyanomelana, Cyornis hainanus       ABC, ABC    
#7 Animalia Chordata Aves     Pelecaniform… Threskiornith… Pseudibis davisoni, Thaumatibis gigantea       XYZ, XYZ
```

Using this method you don't loose any information and also reduce number of rows in the dataframe. You can add/remove columns from `group_by` and `summarise_at` based on your preference.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this doesn't produce a narrower table which is the aim.

Answer (score 0):

Although the original question was about doing this in R, I realised it was quicker and simpler to use PivotTables in Excel, adding each higher classification to the rows, from highest to lowest, then using a VLOOKUP to add the addition data required.

[image]